# Fishpig - Display featured image outside of wordpress template

Tags: magento-1, third-party-module, wordpress

I'm trying to get the featured image from a wordpress page to display outside of the fishpig template. My site uses banners from Magento for product/category pages, but I also wish to use the same banner area for WordPress featured images if possible.

So for example, if I go to a page created in wordpress and that page has a featured image defined, I'd want that to display in the block which I use for Magento banners.

I've included:

```
<?php if ($featuredImage = $post->getFeaturedImage()): ?>
<a href="<?php echo $post->getPermalink() ?>">
    <img src="<?php echo $featuredImage->getAvailableImage() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($post->getPostTitle()) ?>"/>
</a>
```

...in my banner phtml block, but obviously it needs $post to be defined to work.

To do that I've added (based on some other documentation):

```
<?php $post =  Mage::getResourceModel('wordpress/post')->load(); ?>
```

But again, I'd need an ID in there and I don't really know how to get that either.

So what I'm really asking is how do I get the ID of the current page/post? If I can't get that, is there a way of getting the featured image to display somehow?

Hopefully I'm not being too numb here!
Tom

Answer (score 2):

After emailing back and forth with support, I was told you could pull wordpress posts into other cms pages using FishPig\WordPress\Block\Post\ListPost.  I believe extending this could possibly show the featured image of a post only.  I haven't tried implementing to, for instance the homepage, but this seems like it could work.